# Swipe to kill app in activity B but Activity A called onDestroy

Tags: android, android-activity, android-ondestroy

I have two activities: `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. In each activity, I have create a button with onClick method to `startActivity` to another activity.

**ActivityA.java**

```
public void doNext(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
}
```

**ActivityB.java**

```
public void doBack(View view) {
    finish();
}
```

When I press `doNext` it navigated me to the **ActivityB**, I kill the app on the **ActivityB**, but the `onDestroy` on **ActivityA** got called (it must be the `onDestroy` on the ActivityB). Can somebody explain me what happened?

This is the flow of my program: onCreate (A) -> onStart (A) -> onResume (A) -> onPause (A) -> onCreate (B) -> onStart (B) -> onResume (B) -> onStop (A) -> Kill the app (swipe to dismiss) on **ActivityB** -> onPause (B) -> onStop (B) -> **onDestroy (A)** .

Comment: This is expected behavior. Swiping the app from recent kills the application process of which both the activities are child.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: but i thought it would call `onDestroy (B)` instead of `onDestroy (A)`

Comment: @CallmeK Android won't work on your thoughts buddy, it's better to understand the activity life-cycle.

Comment: how do you check if onDestroy(B) is not called?

Comment: @Sagar: I put the `Log` in every lifecycle callback methods (onCreate .... onDestroy) in each activity